# asdf not recognising python changes and MacOSX terminal works but VSCode has a different version

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, asdf

When I run asdf on my terminal I can see the different python versions available on asdf. It's as if my VSCode terminal is getting the python from pyenv and not from asdf

When i run `asdf global python 3.9.18` in my VSCode terminal , I check with `python --version` and get Python 3.10.5 when I run `which python` I get  `/User/Acier/.pyenv/versions/3.10.5/bin/python` I've tried `asdf reshim python` but issue still persists.

On my local terminal I can change my versions when running `asdf list` but this is not showing in VSCode even after I kill the terminal.

Here is my .zshrc \

```
source $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
. /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
. /usr/local/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
```

Comment: You have to use shortcuts ***Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to change your python interpreter instead of changing it in your terminal.

Comment: What part of VS Code do you mean by "not showing in VSCode"? In Python extension, in Jupyter extension, in VS Code terminal's `python` execution?